# Passing a linked list data structure to multiple classes in Java

Tags: java, class, structure

How can I  pass a linked list to multiple classes? I have a linked list that is created in a class, and I want to pass it to multiple classes. Knowing that I want to avoid passing by object since the linked list is large and I want to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Why not declare the Linked list as `protected static` in a parent class, so that child objects can access the same instance of linked list?

Comment: doesn't it matter how big the data is, as there reference is always passed along ?!

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I thought it is as c language where passing by object and passing by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shouldnt be a problem since you only pass the reference to that list to other objects. That means you have only one big list. 
But you should be aware that every object that has a reference to that list can change it

Answer (score -1):

Well in Java, you only pass object "by reference"...

From the link in the comments:

> Let’s be a little bit more specific by what we mean here: objects are
>   passed by reference – meaning that a reference/memory address is
>   passed when an object is assigned to another – BUT (and this is what’s
>   important) that reference is actually passed by value.

Comment: This is wrong. Java passes by value only.  References are passed by value because a copy of the reference value is created and passed.

Comment: You might be interested into reading this perhaps: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-by-value/

Comment: That quote is put out of context. Here are quotes you should have read: "Java passes everything ***by value***, and ***not by reference*** – make sure you remember that". And this one: "And when we say everything, we mean everything – ***objects***, arrays (which are objects in Java), primitive types (like ints and floats), etc. – these are all passed by value in Java." And this one, most importantly : "As we said in the beginning of this article – ***everything*** is passed by value in Java. So, ***objects are not passed by reference in Java***. "

Comment: If pass by reference was possible, you could have method which modifies reference which was passed to it and have it to point to different object than it did before entering method.

Comment: When you say in bold "objects are not passed by reference in Java", it's actually not totally true. The reference to the object is pass by value. The object exist once and only once in memory. If the object itself is pass by value, then the object should have been copied in memory, but that not the case.

Comment: In the answer it is stated that the object is passed by reference. It is passed by value of reference. Not by reference. It is as simple as that.